# Installing Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on a project that requires me to install Rails 2.3.4. I have only  worked with Rails 3 applications, where I installed Rails 3 using RVM.

Since I am using a separate machine for this project, basically all I am asking for is how to install Rails 2.3.4. Any links would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try

```
sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

RVM http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ is your best bet.

Which OS are you working with ?

The installation guide is for Linux. I don't have much experience with RVM on windows. But should be straightforward.

With RVM you get create gemsets which will give you advantage that you can run different rails version for different applications.

http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/

Answer (score 0):

`gem install rails -v 2.3.4`
`gem install --help` for more information.

There is no reason why the above can not be executed via `rvm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install -v=2.3.4 rails
```

or

```
sudo gem install -v=2.3.4 rails
```

It will install rails 2.3.4 version.